# Yarn building not working (Build failed with error code: 1)

Tags: python, node.js, npm, sass, yarnpkg

After run the command `yarn` in the source folder of my project `./src` , I got this error, and i don't know how to fix it ...

```
PS C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src> yarn
yarn install v1.22.11
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.      
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/2] ⠁ waiting...
error C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\mbaye\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\web-projects\\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\\exercice-01\\src\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.16.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\mbaye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\mbaye\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mbaye\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\web-projects\\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\\exercice-01\\src\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\mbaye\OneDrive\Bureau\web-projects\recrutement-alternant-2021-main\exercice-01\src\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have a problem with the python directory, Node JS is trying to load python interpreter and you have some issue with the directory.

You can configure your Python path in NodeJS with this command:

`npm config set python /path/to/executable/python`

Also be sure you have installed Python. You can download and install from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/